# illustrator transform part of a curve

Tags: adobe-illustrator, transform, bezier-curve

I'm very new to AI and am still learning about curves. I would like to know if it is possible to apply transforms to the curve between two anchor points. Specifically, I would like to increase the stroke size between two anchor points but would also like to know if other operations are possible also. When I scale currently it only increases the handle size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can alter stroke widths in *sections* of paths via the **Width Tool**. In some cases it may not be as precise as you'd like. For example, it smooths the stroke variations between one another.

If you are looking for one section of a path that is thicker, with square, abrupt edges - you are better off duplicating that sections, pasting it on top of the original and then altering the weight of its stroke.

Comment: thanks. this kinda helps. I guess it'll work better the more points I add.